# How to use regex expression in jstl?

Tags: java, regex, jsp, jstl

I have defined a function in tld file.And it works well.But if I want to pass a parameter from the jsp,it show wrong.What's wrong with it?

```
 public static boolean matcheTelcom(CharSequence str) { 
    public static String regTelcom="^(((153|133)\\d{8})|((1704|1707)\\d{7}))$";
     return Pattern.compile(Constant.regTelcom).matcher(str).matches();
      }
```

Now,I want to change it to this:

```
public static boolean matches(String pattern, CharSequence str) {
        return Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(str).matches();
      }
```

And in the jsp,I pass it like this:

```
 <c:if test="${mapping:matches('^(((153|133)\\d{8})|((1704|1707)\\d{7}))$',data.phone)}">  
     This is a phone
  </c:if>
```

The error shows:Within a quoted String only [], ['] and ["] may be escaped with [].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `\\\\d` instead of `\\d`.

> The resean why you shoud use four `\` because in java language `\`
>   have transferred meaning.you should use  `\\` means `\`,so does the
>   same in regex expression.

Comment: Can you tell me why use  four `\`?It works well in my java code when I use two `\`.

Comment: Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.